# awk to select CSV file columns greater than a certain number

Tags: awk

I have a CSV file named as `"awk_column_select_test.csv"`

```
a,b,c
0.2,0.4,0.5
0.3,0.6,0.7
0.4,0.8,0.9
```

I was trying to write an awk code to select the rows where either column 1 or column 2 or column 3 is great than 0.5.

My awk program, named "awk_select_column_test.awk" looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {FS=","; cutoff="0.5"} 
{$1 > cutoff || $2 > cutoff || $3 > cutoff}
END {print}
```

Then, I tried to run on command line using:

```
awk -f awk_select_column_test.awk awk_column_select_test.csv
```

I got the following output with only 1 row:

```
0.4,0.8,0.9
```

However, I was hoping to get 2 rows like this:

```
0.3,0.6,0.7
0.4,0.8,0.9
```

Comment: Thank you all for your great help. I tried to remove quote of 0.5, and remove the curly brackets {}, and the "END {print}". Then, it works. The functional code like this:

Comment: `BEGIN {FS=","; cutoff=0.5}` 
`$1 > cutoff || $2 > cutoff || $3 > cutoff ` Surprisingly, if I quote 0.5 or use the curly {}, or use the "END {print}", it would not work.                                             I was wondering whether you could explain why it doesn't work to quote 0.5, or using the curly {}, or use the last print statement. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have extra curly brackets `{}` and `END` block print last line, the logic is all right.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {FS=","; cutoff=0.5} 
NR>1 && ($1 > cutoff || $2 > cutoff || $3 > cutoff){print}
```

This can be written, also

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {FS=","; cutoff=0.5} 
NR>1 && ($1 > cutoff || $2 > cutoff || $3 > cutoff)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Would you please explain why parenthesis (), but not curly {},  around " $1 > cutoff || $2 > cutoff || $3 > cutoff" works? Thanks!

Comment: `{ x|y }` means `true { x | y }`  true is value by default, and `x|y` is boolean operation whose return is lost ..... instead of `x|y { print }`  abbreviated to `x|y` means print if `x|y` operation is true

Comment: Hi Jose, Thanks a lot for your explanation!